# how to make two Spark RDD run parallel

Tags: apache-spark

For example I created two RDDs in my code as following:

```
val rdd1=sc.esRDD("userIndex1/type1")
val rdd2=sc.esRDD("userIndex2/type2")
val rdd3=rdd1.join(rdd2)
rdd3.foreachPartition{....}
```

I found they were executed serially, why not Spark run them parallel? 
The reason of my question is that the network is very slow, for generating rdd1 need 1 hour and generating rdd2 needs 1 hour as well. So I asked why Spark didn't generate the two RDDs at the same time.

Comment: What do you expect here. This piece of code doesn't really do anything. If you execute asynchronous actions then it typically means that there is no enough resources.

Comment: Spark executes your code the way you write it. If you want to perform operation on one RDD which will produce another and used along with your second RDD(for eg join) then you second RDD will be waiting for the previous operation to complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark provide the asynchronous action to run all jobs in asynchronously so it will may be help in you use case to run all computation in parallel + concurrent. AT a time only one RDD will be computed in spark cluster but u can make them asynchronous. you can check java docs for this api here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/AsyncRDDActions.html

And there is also a blog about it check it out here https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/10/21/demystifying-asynchronous-actions-in-spark/

Answer (score 0):

I have found similar behavior. Running RDDs either in Serial or parallel doesn't make any difference due to the number of executors, executor cores you set in your spark-submit.

Let's say we have 2 RDDs as you mentioned above. Let's say each RDD takes 1 hr with 1 executor and 1 core each. We cannot increase the performance with 1 executor and 1 core (Spark config), even if spark runs both RDDs in parallel unless you increase the executors and cores.

So, Running two RDDs in parallel is not going to increase the performance.